# Is there a way to call a function as an attribute (`foo.function()` --> `foo.attribute`)?

Tags: python

I'm writing a function to find a specific attribute of an object and set that attribute to another value. Is there a way to use a function to specify the attribute to affect?

I am trying to modify the attribute specified by `mouseNumber` where `cage[cageNumber]` returns a class object. For example: I am looking for mouse 3 in cage 101, `cage[101].m3`. Each mouse has an "m" before its number, which is where the problem is coming from. I would like to change `cage[101].m3 = True` to `cage[101].m3 = False`. I would call the function like this:
`sacrifice(101, 3)`.

I've tried:

```
def sacrifice(cageNumber, mouseNumber):
    cage[cageNumber].exec(f'm{mouseNumber}') = False
```

giving `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

and

```
def sacrifice(cageNumber, mouseNumber):
    mouseNumber = exec(f'm{mouseNumber}')
    cage[cageNumber].mouseNumber = False
```

giving `NameError: name 'm3' is not defined`

*background:* I'm writing a snippet of code to keep track of and consolidate mice in their cages. Each cage is a class instance and each mouse is an attribute of each cage. Each cage holds 5 mice (m1, m2, m3, m3, m5). There may be only be 1 of each number in each cage, but they may be moved around from cage to cage if there is an opening. My goal is to minimize number of cages by moving around mice.

*Edit:* The cages are contained in a dictionary

Comment: Will this work for editing an attribute? cage[cageNumber] returns a class object, then I want to change the attribute of the object. Is `[]` notation another way of signaling an attribute? The attribute is not a string, does that matter?

Comment: You almost certainly don't mean "class object", you aren't returning a *class* are you? You are working with an *instance of a class*. In any event, it's all just objects.

Comment: Yep you're right, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sacrifice(cageNumber, mouseNumber):
    setattr(cage[cageNumber],"m{}".format(str(mouseNumber)), False)
```

`setattr` allows you to access an object based on a string name. So for example, `my_object.my_attritue = 3` could also be written as `setattr(my_object, "my_attribute", 3)`

You can use `getattr` in a similar fashion to fetch a value. I.e. `print(my_object.my_attribute)` could be written as `print(getattr(my_object, "my_attribute"))`

Comment: Thanks, this is fantastic.